# Apache/Php throw me 504 error after 60 seconds

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, timeout

One website installed in a Ubuntu server with Apache 2.4 throw me 504 errors some times when the process is very large. I edited .htacces and php.ini to get this values:

```
memory_limit 756M
max_execution_time 18000
max_input_time 18000
default_socket_timeout 180
```

If I check the **phpinfo()** data, these values are present and loaded correctly. Even so, the process still throw me a 504 error after 60 seconds.

I Checked the logs and there is no errors. However, I noticed doing a test it would seem that the PHP process is still running until two or three minutes after the browser already threw me the 504 Timeout. I thought that maybe it could be the Apache Timeout, but reviewing it in apache2.conf, has a value of 300 that is much more than what the process actually takes.

```
Timeout 300
```

What other thing could be?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing same problem. Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Had the same annoying problem - it was a load balancer timeout issue. We're using AWS load balancer and it's default timeout was 60 seconds, this was a pain to catch, hope it could help others.

Comment: @Rony that did it for me, two years later. This should be the answer!